# How to check whether response JSON of an API is empty or has an error?

Tags: reactjs, fetch, response

I am new to reactjs and I am stuck in one problem. I am calling an Update API which is of PUT type. I use the fetch function to call the API in reactjs and I check the response of the API. If Response is 200 OK, then I return the `response.json()` and then check whether the json object has error in it or not. If it has error, then I print the error else I update it.

But when there is no Error present in the response, then I get a syntax-error in `return response.json()` statement and If there is actually a Error present in the response then there is no syntax-error shown. So is there a method to check whether the response is empty or not so that accordingly I can return `response.json()`.

I have tried by putting a condition as `if(response.json() != '')` but it shows error in `response.json()` statement.

```
fetch( API + name , {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
         'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name,
        description: updateDesc
      }),
    }).then(function(response) {
      if(response.status == '200'){
        flag=true;
        return response.json();
      }
      else {
        flag=false
      }
    })
    .then(json => {
    if(flag)
    {
        if(json.Error != "")
        {
          that.createNotification('error','update');
        }
        else {
          this.createNotification('success','update');
        }
    }
});
```

Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: If the response code is above 400,you can use a catch block to catch an error ,or else you can directly do res.json().Something like this
fetch("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees").then(res=>res.json()).then(r=>console.log("data",r);).catch(err=>console.log("error ",err));

Comment: @RajeshKumaran But the status code is 200OK for both the case, for error and for success. So How can I check that whether response JSON is present or not?

Comment: Have you looked at (debugger or `console.log` the whole `response` object? Maybe this is an issue more with the API?

Comment: if the response code is 200 , then you will be having a key called error right,then how will u identify its an error

Comment: The problem is solved, actually if the status code is 200, then if there is no error then the line response.json() will throw an error as there is no response. So I return response.text(), then the problem is solved as now I can check whether response.text() is empty or not. IF empty, then there is no error else error is present in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues with this imo:

1. The callback should be refactored to avoid the use of the flag variable. The code in the function supplied to handlers like `then`, `catch` and `finally` of promises is executed asynchronously. Therefore you cannot be sure / (should not assume) when this value will be assigned and in which state your context is at that time.
2. `.then(json => {` if there is an error this will actually use the promise returned by `fetch` aka `response` and not the promise returned by `response.json()` (Currently `return response.json()` is only executed in the success case)

Note that this happens (currently works in the error case) because you can chain promises. You can find more info and examples about this [here](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining)

I would refactor the handling of the fetch promise like this:

- You can shorten the following example and avoid assigning the promises, but it makes the example better readable
- [More information about the response object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

```js
const fetchPromise = fetch(url, { method: 'PUT', ...yourParams });

fetchPromise.then(response => {
  if (response.ok()){
    //Your request was successful
    const jsonPromise = response.json();
    jsonPromise.then(data => {
      console.log("Successful request, parsed json body", data);
    }).catch(error => {
      //error handling for json parsing errors (empty body etc.)
      console.log("Successful request, Could not parse body as json", error);
    })
  } else {
    //Your request was not successful
    /*
     You can check the body of the response here anyways. Maybe your api does return a json error?
    */
  }
}).catch(error => {
  //error handling for fetch errors
}))
```